# C Macro definition in Microchip Graphics Library: How does it work?

Tags: c, graphics, macros

This is a definition in the Microchip Legato Graphics library.
I do not understand what that does. Maybe someone here knows what this is trying to do?

Whilst I write a lot of C, I am not across this type of stuff and I am struggling to port older code to fit in with this library.

Here is the definition of the Macro and related structures in header files.

```
typedef struct leDynamicString
{
    leString base;                      /**< base data */
    const leDynamicStringVTable* fn;    /**< function table */
    leChar*     data;                   /**< data storage */
    uint16_t    capacity;               /**< string capacity */
    uint16_t    length;                 /**< string length */
    const leFont*  font;                /**< string font */
} leDynamicString;



#define LE_STRING_VTABLE(THIS_TYPE) \
    void        (*destructor)(THIS_TYPE* _this); \
    leFont*     (*getFont)(const THIS_TYPE* _this); \
    leResult    (*setFont)(THIS_TYPE* _this, const leFont* font); \
    leResult    (*setFromString)(THIS_TYPE* _this, const struct leString* src); \
    leResult    (*setFromChar)(THIS_TYPE* _this, const leChar* buf, uint32_t size); \
    leResult    (*setFromCStr)(THIS_TYPE* _this, const char* cstr); \
    leChar      (*charAt)(const THIS_TYPE* _this, uint32_t idx); \
    uint32_t    (*length)(const THIS_TYPE* _this); \
    leBool      (*isEmpty)(const THIS_TYPE* _this); \
    int32_t     (*compare)(const THIS_TYPE* _this, const struct leString* tgt); \
    leResult    (*append)(THIS_TYPE* _this, const struct leString* val); \
    leResult    (*insert)(THIS_TYPE* _this, const struct leString* val, uint32_t idx); \
    leResult    (*remove)(THIS_TYPE* _this, uint32_t idx, uint32_t count); \
    void        (*clear)(THIS_TYPE* _this); \
    uint32_t    (*toChar)(const THIS_TYPE* _this, leChar* buf, uint32_t size); \
    leResult    (*getRect)(const THIS_TYPE* _this, leRect* rect); \
    uint32_t    (*getLineCount)(const THIS_TYPE* _this); \
    leResult    (*getLineRect)(const THIS_TYPE* _this, uint32_t line, leRect* rect); \
    leResult    (*getLineIndices)(const THIS_TYPE* _this, uint32_t line, uint32_t* start, uint32_t* end); \
    leResult    (*getCharRect)(const THIS_TYPE* _this, uint32_t idx, leRect* rect); \
    leResult    (*getCharIndexAtPoint)(const THIS_TYPE* _this, const lePoint* pt, uint32_t* idx); \
    leResult    (*_draw)(const THIS_TYPE* _this, int32_t x, int32_t y, leHAlignment align, leColor clr, uint32_t a); \
    void        (*preinvalidate)(THIS_TYPE* _this); \
    void        (*invalidate)(THIS_TYPE* _this); \
    leResult    (*setPreInvalidateCallback)(THIS_TYPE* _this, leString_InvalidateCallback, void* userData); \
    leResult    (*setInvalidateCallback)(THIS_TYPE* _this, leString_InvalidateCallback, void* userData); \

typedef struct leStringVTable
{
    LE_STRING_VTABLE(struct leString)
} leStringVTable;


static const leDynamicStringVTable dynamicStringVTable =
{
    // base class funcs
    .invalidate = (void*)_leString_Invalidate,
    .setPreInvalidateCallback = (void*)_leString_SetPreInvalidateCallback,
    .setInvalidateCallback = (void*)_leString_SetInvalidateCallback,

    // member funcs
    .destructor = _leDynamicString_Destructor,
    .setFromString = _leDynamicString_SetFromString,
    .setFromChar = _leDynamicString_SetFromChar,
    .setFromCStr = _leDynamicString_SetFromCStr,
    .charAt = _leDynamicString_CharAt,
    .length = _leDynamicString_Length,
    .isEmpty = _leDynamicString_IsEmpty,
    .compare = _leDynamicString_Compare,
    .append = _leDynamicString_Append,
    .insert = _leDynamicString_Insert,
    .remove = _leDynamicString_Remove,
    .clear = _leDynamicString_Clear,
    .toChar = _leDynamicString_ToChar,
    .getCapacity = _leDynamicString_GetCapacity,
    .setCapacity = _leDynamicString_SetCapacity,
};

struct leDynamicString;

static const leDynamicStringVTable dynamicStringVTable;

/******************************And here is the MACRO ****/


#define LE_DYNAMICSTRING_VTABLE(THIS_TYPE) \
    LE_STRING_VTABLE(THIS_TYPE) \
    \
        uint32_t (*getCapacity)(THIS_TYPE* str); \
        leResult (*setCapacity)(THIS_TYPE* str, uint32_t cap); \

typedef struct leDynamicStringVTable
{
    LE_DYNAMICSTRING_VTABLE(struct leDynamicString)
} leDynamicStringVTable;
```

And it is used in this function:
Edit: Not directly but the variable dynamicStringVTable unravels into that macro

```
static const leDynamicStringVTable dynamicStringVTable;


void leDynamicString_Constructor(leDynamicString* _this)
{

    _this->base.fn = (void*)&dynamicStringVTable; //Here 
    _this->fn = (void*)&dynamicStringVTable;
}
```

Comment: The *used like this* part doesn't use the macro. The macro definition is missing what `LE_STRING_VTABLE` expands into. Missing is the definition of `leDynamicString`.

Comment: I have edited it to add the missing bits. (Hopefully). In the Constructor function, the 1st line, uses "&dynamicStringVTable" and when I follow that through "static const leDynamicStringVTable dynamicStringVTable;"  and then through "typedef struct leDynamicStringVTable" it ends up in that macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dynamicStringVTable` is a static constant of type `leDynamicStringVTable`.

`leDynamicStringVTable` is a structure. Because it uses several nested macros in its definition, it takes some time to unravel it step by step, but that's all it is.

So:

```
typedef struct leDynamicStringVTable
{
    LE_DYNAMICSTRING_VTABLE(struct leDynamicString)
} leDynamicStringVTable;
```

Expands to:

```
typedef struct leDynamicStringVTable
{
    LE_STRING_VTABLE(struct leDynamicString)
    uint32_t (*getCapacity)(struct leDynamicString* str);
    leResult (*setCapacity)(struct leDynamicString* str, uint32_t cap);
} leDynamicStringVTable;
```

And this expands to:

```
typedef struct leDynamicStringVTable
{
    void        (*destructor)(struct leDynamicString* _this);
    leFont*     (*getFont)(const struct leDynamicString* _this);
    leResult    (*setFont)(struct leDynamicString* _this, const leFont* font);
    /* ... a bunch of other function pointers ... */
    void        (*preinvalidate)(struct leDynamicString* _this);
    void        (*invalidate)(struct leDynamicString* _this);
    leResult    (*setPreInvalidateCallback)(struct leDynamicString* _this, leString_InvalidateCallback, void* userData);
    leResult    (*setInvalidateCallback)(struct leDynamicString* _this, leString_InvalidateCallback, void* userData);
    uint32_t (*getCapacity)(struct leDynamicString* str);
    leResult (*setCapacity)(struct leDynamicString* str, uint32_t cap);
} leDynamicStringVTable;
```

The static constant `dynamicStringVTable` is initialized with some functions:

```
static const leDynamicStringVTable dynamicStringVTable =
{
    // base class funcs
    .invalidate = (void*)_leString_Invalidate,
    .setPreInvalidateCallback = (void*)_leString_SetPreInvalidateCallback,
    .setInvalidateCallback = (void*)_leString_SetInvalidateCallback,

    // member funcs
    .destructor = _leDynamicString_Destructor,
    /* ... */
};
```

And the pointer to this instance is used to initialize two pointers in the constructor function `leDynamicString_Constructor`.

Comment: That is a great answer. It now looks completely understandable. Tx